how to fix NullInjectorError caused by NotificationService imported form carbon components angular ? (migrate carbon from v4 to v5)
I'm using Carbon UI in Angular. I updated Angular to v17 and also updated Carbon to v5, and it gave me an error. When I delete the notification service import from the service, the error disappears.
Do yoy now how to fix it ?
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1100:40)
at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)
at Object.NotificationService_Factory \[as factory\] (carbon-components-an…fication.mjs:22:102)
at core.mjs:3219:47
at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:866:9)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3218:21)
Zone - Promise.then (async)     
(anonymous) @   src_app_origination-…form_module_ts.js:1

I've googled, and there is not much information about carbon. I've also read Carbon's documentation, but I didn't find anything useful.

FIX:
I fixed it by adding NotificationService straight to the component provider where I'm using it (I'm using NotificationService in SomeService and then doing something with it).
I found this solution in this git discussion.
https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-angular/issues/2763
